# DKIM record failing

Tags: domain-name-system, dkim

I am trying to setup DKIM for my mail server (iRedMail).

I am using the DNS on vultr and have setup the the record as:

```
dkim._domainkey.declanmarks.pw
"v=DKIM1;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCoKemrl1gEfXj6pUy20nyZIP7CHveg1Djs3usW1EBdaZG/IY4NRaNnCUJT+tpXGAbj5LKhQ9WeSnnO62l3YxvIizEz5XHWeunQmo3iwsplz0K+Zjmv29MDZfQ3QsfirxwFzZFLqyPzhHaeFamgTdHDLLeislzS5iOmDDZLdogd/wIDAQAB"
```

When I check using this tool http://dkimcore.org/c/keycheck I get an error saying (A public-key (p=) is required)

The output of installing iRedMail showed this for the DKIM:

```
; key#1 1024 bits, i=dkim, d=declanmarks.pw, /var/lib/dkim/declanmarks.pw.pem
dkim._domainkey.declanmarks.pw. 3600 TXT (
  "v=DKIM1; p="
  "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCoKemrl1gEfXj6pUy20nyZIP7C"
  "Hveg1Djs3usW1EBdaZG/IY4NRaNnCUJT+tpXGAbj5LKhQ9WeSnnO62l3YxvIizEz"
  "5XHWeunQmo3iwsplz0K+Zjmv29MDZfQ3QsfirxwFzZFLqyPzhHaeFamgTdHDLLei"
  "slzS5iOmDDZLdogd/wIDAQAB")
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out in the selector box in http://dkimcore.org/c/keycheck I entered the wrong information. I entered dkim._domainkey when I should have entered just dkim. Which ment it was going to dkim._domainkey._domainkey.declanmarks.pw. I only realised when I read that on the title of the page.